# Other people can't run EAZFuscated programs that I've made

Tags: vb.net, eazfuscator

I've did research and still can't figure this out, but I know the problem. The problem is that Eazfuscator isn't installed on other peoples pc, but how would I get them to run it without getting this error, and without them installing eazfuscator? Or should I use another one?

> Error when running protected application:
>
> This application has been built with an evaluation version of Eazfuscator.NET, and therefore cannot be distributed. You can install Eazfuscator.NET on this computer to be able to run this application.

Comment: Buy the full version would be my best guess?

Comment: that is an odd way to protect a tool.  of course you are going to want to test the deliverable on other machines before buying.  doesnt make much sense to install the tool for that kind of test.  There is an open source Obfuscator which works differently than Eaz but has a more options: ConfuserEx; you might also look around for the last free version of Eaz (3.3) - they were DonateWare until very recently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to purchase a developers license plain and simple. Until then they will see this message. When you get the license and compile the application this wont happen...

More about it here...

http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/purchase